# JavaScript show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know if there is a way to make certain div's hide when clicking on a div box?

Upon clicking on the box, some applications div's will hide. Here is the first image: 
[image]

Upon the boxes hiding, the other div's will realign in the spot of the current div's and then move back to standard view.
Second image:

[image]

Code:

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <button onclick="projectCollab()"><div id="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate on Projects</div></button>
     </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate on Files</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate Socially</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <div id="decisionTreeOneDrive"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/onedrive-logo.png" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>OneDrive</h3></div>
     </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeProject"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/Project.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Project</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeSharePoint"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/SharePointDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>SharePoint</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeTeams"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/TeamsDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Teams</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreePlanner"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/PlannerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Planner</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeYammer"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/YammerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Yammer</h3></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script>
    function projectCollab() {
     var x = document.getElementById("decisionTreeOneDrive");
     if (x.style.display === "none") {
         x.style.display = "block";
     } else {
         x.style.display = "none";
     }
 }
 </script>
</div>
```

Disregard the JavaScript code in the text back it didn't seem to work properly at all.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 @AdamAzad

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents We don't do "SOLVED" in titles here

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for the update bud! I'm new so I wasn't sure if I should update people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have div's with similair ID's. Try use another selector, as example data attributes.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-collaborate="projects" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate on Projects</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-collaborate="files" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate on Files</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-collaborate="socially" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate Socially</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreeOneDrive"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/onedrive-logo.png" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>OneDrive</h3></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreeProject"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/Project.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Project</h3></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeSharePoint"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/SharePointDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>SharePoint</h3></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeTeams"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/TeamsDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Teams</h3></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreePlanner"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/PlannerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Planner</h3></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreeYammer"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/YammerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Yammer</h3></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
            function projectCollab(){
                var divsToCange = document.querySelectorAll('[data-decision]'),
                    attr = this.getAttribute('data-collaborate');

                for(var i=0; i<divsToCange.length; i++){
                    var d = divsToCange[i];

                    if(d.getAttribute('data-decision') == attr){
                        d.style.display = (!d.style.display) ? 'none' : '';
                    }else{
                        d.style.display = '';
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }

            var divButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-collaborate]');

            for(var i=0; i<divButtons.length; i++){
                divButtons[i].addEventListener('click', projectCollab);
            }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Vitalii, that does help but I tried that already and all it goes it hides the single div and doesn't push the other next div in its spot. All that does it make the div disappear and the page starts reloading.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents I modified code. I hope it will helpfull.

Comment: It helps so much @vitalii! I'm still having the issue with filling in the white boxes once the div's disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQuery `.toggle()` function to toggle between hide and show and it will auto arrange the adjacent div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#decisionTreeBox').on('click', function() {
    $('#test').toggle('show');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <button onclick="projectCollab()"><div id="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate on Projects</div></button>
     </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate on Files</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate Socially</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;" id="test">
      <div id="decisionTreeOneDrive"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/onedrive-logo.png" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>OneDrive</h3></div>
     </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeProject"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/Project.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Project</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeSharePoint"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/SharePointDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>SharePoint</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeTeams"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/TeamsDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Teams</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreePlanner"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/PlannerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Planner</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="decisionTreeYammer"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/YammerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Yammer</h3></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    

 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @suzan, thanks for the input! I will test this now.

UPDATE: This works by hiding the div, so I appreciate the help with that.  Upon clicking on the box, it makes the page refresh, is there a reason for this?

Comment: no, it does not refresh the page. It simply toggles the style for the particular div on click.

Answer (score 0):

Which element you want to hide show you can call function onclick="function(this)" with this parameter.
try this given example Below.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
             <button onclick="projectCollab(this)"><div class="container">
```

Collaborate on Projects
        
        
            Collaborate on Files
        
        
            Collaborate Socially

---

OneDrive
        
        
            Project
        
        
            SharePoint
        
        
            Teams
        
        
            Planner
        
        
            Yammer
        
      
    
    function projectCollab() {
        var x = document.getElementById("decisionTreeOneDrive");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

Comment: Hi @dipak harishbhai, thanks for the input! This works but it does not make the div's align in the spots of the current boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The the HTML is just a copy of yours, but the JS functions below should help you out if you prefer to use js instead of jquery.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
            <button onclick="projectCollab()"><div id="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate on Projects</div></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate on Files</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">Collaborate Socially</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="decisionTreeOneDrive"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/onedrive-logo.png" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>OneDrive</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="decisionTreeProject"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/Project.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Project</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="decisionTreeSharePoint"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/SharePointDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>SharePoint</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="decisionTreeTeams"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/TeamsDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Teams</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="decisionTreePlanner"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/PlannerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Planner</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="decisionTreeYammer"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/YammerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Yammer</h3></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script>
    function projectCollab() {
        var x = document.getElementById("decisionTreeOneDrive").setAttribute("onclick", hide());
    }
    function hide(){
        var sharepoint = document.getElementById("decisionTreeSharePoint");
        var planner = document.getElementById("decisionTreePlanner");
        if (sharepoint.style.display === "none") {
            sharepoint.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            sharepoint.style.display = "none";
        }

        if (planner.style.display === "none") {
            planner.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            planner.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Daisy Priede, I will be testing this out right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're encountering two issues.

1. You want to toggle the squares below.
2. You want the boxes to collapse in the space that is remaining.

To solve issue #1 - I created a vanilla javascript toggle that doesn't rely on any frameworks.

This requires three updates to the HTML

- Creating the onClick toggle function on each button: `onclick=toggleSquares('DESTINATION');`
- Adding the destination to the CSS column element ( solves #2 ) you want toggled:  `data-toggle="files"`
- Adding a CSS class hook ( optional ) on the CSS column element.

`<button onclick=toggleSquares('projects')>
        <div id="decisionTreeBox">Collaborate on Projects</div>
 </button>`

...

```
<div class="col-md-4 square" data-toggle="projects">
    <div>
          <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings">OneDrive</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

The javascript function looks something like this:

```
function toggleSquares(type){
   var getSquares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

  getSquares.forEach(function(element){

    if(element.getAttribute('data-toggle') != type) {
      element.classList.add('display-none');
    }
    else {
      element.classList.remove('display-none');
    }
  })
}
```

To step through the interaction:

1. On click grab all of the elements that have the '.square' class and add them to a variable local to the function.
2. Loop through that variables object and compare them to the `type` that has been passed down through the function
3. If the element does not match the type that has been passed down -- add a css class with the 'display: none' attribute.
4. If the element does match the type that has been passed down -- remove the css class if it had been added in step 3.

Here's a codepen that outlines the above interaction: https://codepen.io/MathiasaurusRex/pen/aKZbqR

Comment: Thanks for the update @Mathias! I will take all these suggestions and test them out right now.