# Using more than one div on show/hide

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is related to my original Question, which was solved: [JavaScript show/hide divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706377/javascript-show-hide-divs)

So I have gone with Fadi's answer on the original question and it works perfectly. How would I be able to use two div's for the same data-collaboration category?

[image]

[image]

I want to have teams show up under "Collaborate Socially" and "Collaborate on Files" - the categories "project, files, socially" are all using the data-decision definition.

I've tried adding two data-decision="projects" data-decision="socially" in one div and it didn't work.

```html
<div class="outer-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-collaborate="projects" class="decisionTreeBox collabProjects" style="font-size: x-large;">
                    Collaborate on Projects</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-collaborate="files" class="decisionTreeBox collabFiles" style="font-size: x-large;">
                    Collaborate on Files</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-collaborate="socially" class="decisionTreeBox collabSocially" style="font-size: x-large;">
                    Collaborate Socially</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="container" style="padding: 0px;">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/OneDrive.aspx"><div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeOneDrive"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/onedrive-logo.png" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>OneDrive</h3></div>
                </div></a>
            <!-- <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/O365.aspx"><div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreeProject"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/Project.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Project</h3></div>
                </div></a> -->
            <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/SharePointOnline.aspx"><div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeSharePoint"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/SharePointDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>SharePoint</h3></div>
                </div></a>
            <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Teams.aspx"><div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreeTeams"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/TeamsDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Teams</h3></div>
             </div></a>
            <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Planner.aspx"><div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreePlanner"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/PlannerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Planner</h3></div>
             </div></a>
            <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Yammer.aspx"><div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreeYammer"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/YammerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Yammer</h3></div>
             </div></a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        function projectCollab(){
            var divsToCange = document.querySelectorAll('[data-decision]'),
                attr = this.getAttribute('data-collaborate');

            for(var i = 0; i < divsToCange.length; i++){
                var d = divsToCange[i];
                if(d.getAttribute('data-decision') == attr) {
                    d.parentNode.style.display ='block' ;
                  }
                else{
                    d.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        var divButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-collaborate]');

        for(var i = 0; i < divButtons.length; i++){
            divButtons[i].addEventListener('click', projectCollab);
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fix comes easy once you have started with `data` attributes

2 sides of the solution

> HTML

You will be able to stack the values separated by a space

```
data-decision="socially files"
```

> JS

For the HTML to work, we will change your `if` statement where you checked if the data attribute was the *same* as the once selected. Now we are going to validate if the data attribute *includes* the once selected.

This was your if statement

```
if(d.getAttribute('data-decision') == attr)
```

This is the new if statement

```
if (d.getAttribute('data-decision').includes(attr))
```

Hope this helps :>

```js
function projectCollab() {
  var divsToCange = document.querySelectorAll('[data-decision]'),
    attr = this.getAttribute('data-collaborate');

  for (var i = 0; i < divsToCange.length; i++) {
    var d = divsToCange[i];

    if (d.getAttribute('data-decision').includes(attr)) {
      d.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      d.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  return false;
}

var divButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-collaborate]');

for (var i = 0; i < divButtons.length; i++) {
  divButtons[i].addEventListener('click', projectCollab);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <div data-collaborate="projects" class="decisionTreeBox collabProjects" style="font-size: x-large;">
        Collaborate on Projects</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <div data-collaborate="files" class="decisionTreeBox collabFiles" style="font-size: x-large;">
        Collaborate on Files</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <div data-collaborate="socially" class="decisionTreeBox collabSocially" style="font-size: x-large;">
        Collaborate Socially</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="container" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/OneDrive.aspx">
        <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
          <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeOneDrive">
            <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/onedrive-logo.png" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />OneDrive</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <!-- <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/O365.aspx"><div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreeProject"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/Project.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Project</h3></div>
                </div></a> -->
      <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/SharePointOnline.aspx">
        <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
          <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeSharePoint">
            <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/SharePointDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />SharePoint</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Teams.aspx">
        <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
          <div data-decision="socially files" id="decisionTreeTeams">
            <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/TeamsDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />Teams</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Planner.aspx">
        <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
          <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreePlanner">
            <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/PlannerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />Planner</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Yammer.aspx">
        <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
          <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreeYammer">
            <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/YammerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />Yammer</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```